# Solving a regression problem

Tags: regression, matrix-decomposition, matrix-inverse

I wanted to solve such a regression problem:

$$Y = Xb + e$$

where $X$ is a $m$ by $n$ matrix, resulting in: b = (X'X)-1X'Y as a solution. Since $n$ is quite large (2400), I can't use the conventional methods to calculate the inverse of $X'X$. So I thought about using LU Decomposition using Crout method. In this [link](http://mymathlib.webtrellis.net/matrices/linearsystems/crout.html) an implementation of this method is available which requires an $n$ by $n$ matrix $A$ to solve the equation $Ax=B$. Does it mean that I should use $X'X$ matrix as the input ($A$)? Please note that the problem is that it requires an $n$ by $n$ matrix instead of an $m$ by $n$ matrix.

Comment: @Pegah, you omited the dimensions of matrix $A$. Please check that I added them correctly.

Comment: @Pegah, 2400 is not a large n. Such matrix will take about 40 Mb of RAM, which is not a lot for modern computers.

Comment: @mpiktas thanks for the edits. I saw that recursive methods' time complexity is O(n!) in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886280/how-to-find-determinant-of-large-matrix/6215710#6215710) and Crout method is only O(n^3)

Comment: @Pegah  $b = (X'X)^{-1} X'Y$  is just one way of saying that $b$ solves the equation $(X'X)b = X'Y$.  Symbolically replacing $(X'X)\to A$, $X'Y \to B$, and $b \to x$ shows this is *identical* to $Ax = B$.

Comment: @whuber thanks it is the answer. Could you please put it as an answer? So other users can see the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @Pegah Even when I wrote that comment, @aix was well on the way to a good answer.  It looks even better now :-).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say that you need to solve an ordinary least squares problem on 2400 variables.

There are two assumptions that I think you need to revisit:

**Assumption 1**: that you need to compute the inverse of $X^TX$.

**Assumption 2**: that solving ordinary least squares on 2400 variables requires specialized methods.

I'll examine them in turn:

**Assumption 1: that you need to compute the inverse of $X^TX$.**

A better way to solve OLS using normal equations is by computing the Cholesky factorization of $X^TX$. See section 5.3.2 of [Golub and van Loan](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0801854148) for details. They state that the entire algorithm, including computing $X^TX$, $X^Ty$ as well as performing the Cholesky factorization and back-substitution, requires $(m+n/3)n^2$ floating-point operations.

**Assumption 2: that solving ordinary least squares on 2400 variables requires specialized methods.**

You don't say what kind of hardware you have at your disposal, so I'll assume that you have access to a typical mainstream PC.

First of all, a 2400x2400 of 64-bit floats requires just 44MB of memory.

Secondly, computing Cholesky decomposition of a matrix of this size takes half a second on my desktop PC using Numerical Python ([`numpy`](https://numpy.org/)). This is the dominant computation once you have computed $X^TX$ and $X^Ty$.

Comment: hi, the problem is not with the size of n. the problem is that first I am not sure if my matrix in positive definite, so I can't use Cholesky decomposition. and second I don't know how to use Crout method because it needs an n by n matrix but my matrix is n by m.

Comment: @Pegah: I am confused. It is easy to prove that $X^TX$ is positive (semi-)definite for any $X$. Are you alluding to some numerical issues?

Comment: On the other hand, forming $\mathbf X^T \mathbf X$ may not always be the best course of action (you square the condition number, among other things). At the very least, performing a QR decomposition of $\mathbf X$ might be better...